# upload files to dropbox using dropbox api

Tags: vb.net

i'm working in a console app that is going to be executed in a server every week, basically it generates a report in excel and then it has to upload it to a folder in dropbox, i've trying a lot of stuff for that last part i finally got this code that does not work but doesn't throw any exception (before i had one that throw and invalid folder format)

```
            Dim _path As String
            _path = "/Pruebas/" & Path.GetFileName(FilePath)
            Try

                Dim rawData = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)
                Dim str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(rawData)
                Using mem = New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str))
                    Dim Up = I.Files.UploadAsync(_path, body:=mem)                        
                    MsgBox("Successfully Uploaded")
                End Using


            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
```

it doesn't throw exception but also doens't work, any help i'll be thankfull.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial
I know its not vb.net, however it shouldnt be too hard to translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

`Dim Up = I.Files.UploadAsync(_path, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body:=mem)`

Link to documentation: http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_UploadAsync_1.htm